# conda activate tensorflow2.3（python3.8） Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages

Tags: python

I want to install tensorflow2.3.1，so I do these things
conda create -n tensorflow2.3 python=3.8
pip install tensorflow==2.3.1
But when I use spyder to conda activate tensorflow2.3
spyder show Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
so what should I do,thanks for your attention!!